# Text not displaying

Tags: swiftui

I've got this code and it's showing no errors but no text is also displaying. Any solutions?
I’m trying to display the satellites category.
Swift UI, Xcode 14.3(14E222b)

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct Datamodel: Decodable {
    var category: String
    var transactionscount: Int
    var satcount: Int
    var above: [Data]
}

struct Data: Decodable {
    var satid: Int
    var satname: String
    var intDesignator: String
    var launchDate: String
    var satlat: Double
    var satlng: Double
    var satalt: Double
}

struct TestView :  View
{ /// start
    @ObservedObject var fetcher = VerseFetcher()

    var body: some View{ ///  start body
        Text(self.fetcher.verse?.category ?? "")
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
    } /// end body

    public class VerseFetcher : ObservableObject{ /// start verse fetcher
        @Published var verse: Datamodel?

        init(){ /// start init
            load()
        } /// end init

        func load(){ /// start load
            let url = URL(string: "https://api.n2yo.com/rest/v1/satellite/above/41.702/-76.014/0/70/18/&apiKey=<api-key>")!

            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data,response,error) in/// start url session
                do  { /// start do
                    if let d = data { /// start if
                        let webdata = try JSONDecoder().decode(Datamodel.self, from: d)

                        DispatchQueue.main.async { /// start dispatch
                            self.verse = webdata
                        } ///  end dispatch que
                    }   else { /// end if /  start else
                       print("No data")
                    }/// end else
                } catch { ///  end do /  start catch
                    print("Error here")
                } /// end catch
            }.resume()/// end url session
        } /// end load
    } /// end Verse Fetcher
} /// end

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}
```

I probably got something wrong in the text().

Answer (score 1):

**Reason**

The current `response` models for the API calls do not match the JSON response format leading to JSON decoding error. To make it work make the following changes.

**Code**

```swift
struct DataModel: Decodable {
    var info: InfoModel
    var above: [AboveModel]
}

struct InfoModel: Decodable {
    var category: String
    var transactionscount: Int
    var satcount: Int
}

struct AboveModel: Decodable {
    var satid: Int
    var satname: String
    var intDesignator: String
    var launchDate: String
    var satlat: Double
    var satlng: Double
    var satalt: Double
}
```

**Suggestions**

Instead of using generic error messages like "No data" or "Error here," consider printing specific error messages that provide insights into the issue that occurred in your code snippet.